# Value for convergence

Tags: analysis

Im stuck on this exercise:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{b}+b^{-k}} $$

I need to find for which positive real numbers b does this serie converge?

Maybe I shoud compare it with the p-series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{b}} $$
which converges when b>1. But I got no clue how to use this..

Comment: It's very simple to do what you described when $b>1.$ Don't give up so easily.

Comment: So you mean that I should look on the case when b>1 ?
Then we should get this inequality   $$0< \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{b}+b^{-k}} <  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{b}} $$ ?
And then this implies that our series converges when b>1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two series that jump to mind when looking at your series:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^b}, \,\,\, \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{b^{-k}} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b^k. $$

The first is the $p$-series which converges when $b > 1$ and the second is the geometric series which converges when $|b| < 1$.

If $b > 1$, then by comparison with the $p$-series, we have

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^b + b^{-k}} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^b} $$

and so the series converges.

If $0 < b < 1$ then by comparison with the geometric series, we have

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^b + b^{-k}} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b^k $$

and so again, the series converges. When $b = 1$, you get the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k + 1}$ which diverges.

Comment: But doesnt the geometric series converge when |b|< 1 that is -1<b<1 ?

Comment: @fejz1234 Yes, but you wrote in your question "for positive real $b$". It is a good exercise to determine whether your series converges or not for all real $b$.

Comment: Okay thanks. But I dont really understand how you know that the geometric series is bigger then our sereis? (the inequality) Edit: Or nevermind its the same reason why the p-series is bigger , right?

Comment: @fejz1234: Yep. You divide by a smaller number, resulting in a larger number.